# Is it possible to get this part of a string

Tags: javascript

I wonder if it's possible to get this part of a string. 
Here is my  string:

```
var string = "www.somesite.com/o/images%2Fc834vePyJ3SFVk2iO4rU0ke1cSa2%2F12391381_10205760647243398_2385261683139818614_n.jpg?alt=media&token=7a692a38-6982-474f-bea5-459c987ae575";
```

Now I want to be able to grab just this part of the string, the file name:

```
12391381_10205760647243398_2385261683139818614_n.jpg
```

I tried:

```
var result = /[^/]*$/.exec(""+url+"")[0];
```

, but it will return

```
user%2Fc834vePyJ3SFVk2iO4rU0ke1cSa2%2F12391381_10205760647243398_2385261683139818614_n.jpg?alt=media&token=4c92c4d7-8979-4478-a63d-ea190bec87cf
```

My Regex is wrong.

Another this is, the file extension can be .png or jpg so it's not fixed to jpg.

Comment: Why don't you want to use split identifiers ? They could be handy.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question! I don't mine split identifiers.

Comment: [What have you tried that isn't working](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @ManoDestra I tried this var result = /[^/]*$/.exec(""+url+"")[0]; but it will return user%2Fc834vePyJ3SFVk2iO4rU0ke1cSa2%2F12391381_10205760647243398_2385261683139818614_n.jpg?alt=media&token=4c92c4d7-8979-4478-a63d-ea190bec87cf

Comment: You should try something before asking how to solve your problem

Comment: Put that attempt in the body of your question so that others can identify what's wrong with it and then help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex to isolate the part you want :

This works :

```js
var string = "www.somesite.com/o/images%2Fc834vePyJ3SFVk2iO4rU0ke1cSa2%2F12391381_10205760647243398_2385261683139818614_n.jpg?alt=media&token=7a692a38-6982-474f-bea5-459c987ae575";
console.log((string.match(/[A-Za-z0-9_]+.(jpg|png|bmp)/))[0].substring(2));
```

Comment: Nice but the filename can be png or other extensions not fixed to jpg

Comment: I edited my answer : You can specify which extensions to accept like this : `(jpg|png|bmp)`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that may have to be adapted depending on how much the URL string changes:

```js
var string = "www.somesite.com/o/images%2Fc834vePyJ3SFVk2iO4rU0ke1cSa2%2F12391381_10205760647243398_2385261683139818614_n.jpg?alt=media&token=7a692a38-6982-474f-bea5-459c987ae575";

var out = string.split('?')[0].split('%2F')[2];

console.log(out); // "12391381_10205760647243398_2385261683139818614_n.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you always have an url, first I would decode the encoded `/` (`%2F`) characters via:

```
var string = "www.somesite.com/o/images%2Fc834vePyJ3SFVk2iO4rU0ke1cSa2%2F12391381_10205760647243398_2385261683139818614_n.jpg?alt=media&token=7a692a38-6982-474f-bea5-459c987ae575";
var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(string);
```

and then use a regex:

```
decodedUrl.match(/[^/]*(?=[?])/)
```

Mind, that this regex assumes parameters (the part starting with `?...`) are present, so if that's not the case, you might have to alter it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive contributions!

Answer (score 0):

If the filename always has a .jpg extension:

```
var url = decodeURIComponent(string);
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1, url.lastIndexOf(".jpg"))
```

If not:

```
url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
filename = url.substring(0,url.indexOf("?"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the string, it appears that the file name is between the second occurrence of "%2F" and the first occurrence of "?" in the string.

The first step is to get rid of the part of the string before the second "%2F". This can be done by splitting the string at every "%2F" and taking the third element in the resulting array.

```
var intermediate = string.split("%2F")[2]
```

Then, we need to get rid of everything after the "?":

```
var file_name = intermediate.split("?")[0]
```

This should give you the file name from the URL